# Custom placeholder inside element <td> not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery to dynamically add a new row to a table.
I would like to have a placeholder inside the table cells that go away when the user clicks to enter text.
I attempted to make CSS that would do this.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$("#addbutton").click( function(){
    $('#searchresults > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td> <div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Name"></div> </td> \
                                                       <td><div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Description"> </div> </td>
                                                   </tr>')
```

Here is the CSS:

```
<style>
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}
</style>
```

The placeholder text isnt showing up.
Any suggestions ?

*Ive updated the question so that the new line is correctly spliced in the string inside `.append('')` I still cannot get the text to appear. I am using Safari on El Capitan. The new row is added and is editable but the text isnt there !*

**The rows get added and are also editable. Its just that the text is not visible.**

Answer (score 3):

The only problem i see is the new lines: when you need to continue on the next line you need to escape the new line char like in:

```
var str = '11111\
llllllll';
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#addbutton").click(function() {
    $('#searchresults > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td><div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Name"></div></td>\
<td><div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Description"></div></td>\
</tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(data-text)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="addbutton">addbutton</button>
<table id="searchresults">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still cant get the text to show. Strange

Comment: @asehgal Did it work in my snippet?

Comment: It's all about character escaping. Here is a [codePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YWJJEE) made of @gaetanoM code. But if you "escape", like he suggest, at line end **AND**  indent you next line with tabs... Naaah. The escape counted only for the newline char!

Look at my [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xOyyRV) wich allows cool indentation

Comment: Nope. Didnt help either. If line splicing was an issue, it probably wont even add the rows and make the content editable. The rows are added and are also editable. Its just that the text is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#addbutton").click( function(){
    $('#searchresults > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td> <div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Name"></div> </td> \
                                                       <td><div contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter Description"></div></td>
                                                   </tr>')
```

There was a space between `<td> <div>` as seen above. Someone edited the question and removed it.

**Please do not edit questions at your own whim.** Apparently adding space in 
 can screw things up !

Comment: ?? Spaces inside a string isn't the problem. I never saw a problem with a space between à `td` and a `div` in HTML. Problem is string delimitation in JS.

Comment: yes you may be right since I am using HTML INSIDE JS.